# C# How to get current Powerpoint Presentation File Name?

Tags: c#, forms, powerpoint

As you see I have some object in my hand but I couldn't figure out how to get current file name. I am getting _currentSlideName from an xml file and compare to open new slide.
Do you have any suggestion to get current power point presentation file name?

```
   ppt.Application _pptApplication = new ppt.Application();

   private void Open(string fileName)
   { 
     _presentation = _pptApplication.Presentations.Open(fileName, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
   }

   private void CheckSlide()
   {
      if (_oSlideShowView == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Open( _settingObj.Path + _currentSlideName);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Open(_settingObj.Path+ "Test.pptx" );
                    }

                }
                else if (_currentSlideName != _presentation.Path)
                {
                   try
                    {
                        Open( _settingObj.Path + _currentSlideName);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Open(_settingObj.Path+ "Test.pptx" );
                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting the full filename of the open presentation is simply [Presentation.FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746313.aspx). In your case, this would be:

```
_pptApplication.ActivePresentation.FullName
```

Note that this only returns the presentation's name if the file is not currently saved. If it is not saved, the presentation's `Path` is an empty string.

EDIT: The example above returns the full filename. If you want only the name, use the following. Just to clarify that this only makes sense with saved presentations, I've added a check on `Path`.

```
if(!_pptApplication.ActivePresentation.Path.Equals("")) {
    var name = _pptApplication.ActivePresentation.Name
    ... do processing...
}
else {
    ... error ...
}
```

Comment: After saving , I am able to get fullpath but it is still not the presentation file name

Comment: I have still the same Issue. instead of the file has different name it shows presentation1.pptx

Comment: Your issue is something else then. My code returns the file name of the *current* presentation. Do you need it from `_presentation` instead? Then call `_presentation.Name`.